# I'm trying to write some (OOP) for a school assignment and I came up with some problems

Tags: c#, class, oop, methods, attributes

### **First, let me show you the question.**

- *Create a class named "student".*
- *Class' attributes are "name" and "grade".*
- *The class' method is "Rate", which receives the name
  and grade of the student and print "pass" if the grade >= 60, else "failed".*
- *create three different objects for three students.*

---

**I created a class and attributes.
but i didnt know the rest i tried my best.
the teacher did not gave us the set and get method**

***Here is my code:***

```
namespace ProjectOO

{

    class Program

    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            student a = new student("omar", 55);

            Console.WriteLine(a.Rate());

            student b = new student("ahmed", 91);

            Console.WriteLine(b.Rate());

            student c = new student("mohammed", 22);

            Console.WriteLine(c.Rate());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    
    }

    class student
    {
         string name;
         double grade;

        public student()
        {
            name = name;
            grade = grade;
        }

        public void Rate(double grade)
        {
            if (grade >= 60)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("pass");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("fail");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the constructor you have created for the `student` class. It's a *default constructor* (i.e., it has no parameters), but you are calling it with a `string` and an `int` when you create your instances. In the code for the constructor you simply assign your member fields with their values (which does nothing) think about what you really want in that constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `student("omar", 55);` but dont have a constructor for it .

```
class student
{
     string name;
     double grade;

    public student(string name,double grade)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public string Rate()
    {
        if (grade >= 60)
        {
            return "pass";
        }
        else
        {
           return "fail";
        }
    }
}
```

this is rough idea how things work with OOP.

**Problems With your Code :**

1. You have declared a constructor with out params and passing params when creating new Object.
   ( Added params to constructor , used `this` keyword that to remove naming ambiguity)
2. You are calling a method( **Rate()** ) that expects an argument with out arguments.
   (You don't need to pass grade as this is class method and object already has grade value in it.)
3. You are trying to print a function that is returning void.
   (So we are returning a string so when we call the method that method will return a string to print.)

**UPDATE :**
Please look at the @CobyC 's Answer he got the point that i totally missed

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment states.

> The class' method is "Rate", which receives the name and grade of the
> student and print "pass" if the grade >= 60, else "failed

But your implementation of `.Rate` does not match the requirements.

Your Rate method needs to look like this:

```
 public string Rate(string name, double grade)
{
...assign student name and grade
... Implement the pass fail code
.. return the pass or fail string.
}
```

There is no need for a constructor that takes the name and rate.